# Java get latest GitHub release

Tags: java, github, github-api

I had tried to acess to GitHub via Java to get the latest release of a repository and I had found [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release) and I tried to use it with this code:

```
    String url = "https://github.com/:owner/:repo/releases/latest";

    try {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(request);
        String json = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        System.out.println(json);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
```

and the only thing I get as response is the HTML code of the website but I want the json response like you can see in the exaple response [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release).

Comment: Did you set concrete values for `:owner` and `:repo`? Also try to add an `Accept: application/json` header to the request.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the github api but from a quick skim of the docs it looks like you need to be using `"https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest"` as per the url field in the sample response you posted a link to

Comment: and also make sure to set the values for `:owner` and `:repo` as @SteffenKreutz says

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the Help!
Yea, it is right, you have to acess to [api.github.com](http://api.github.com/) and you have to set Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json